# JRE version enough to run a jar

Tags: java

What is the smallest version of JRE to run a simple jar that calls other jars while running ?

Answer (score 4):

That depends completely on what parts of the Standard API and what class file version the classes in that JAR (and the ones it calls) are using.

Comment: I dont know if it give a idea but : I am using JAXB and swing components

Comment: @gustavo: then, since JAXB was added to the standard API library only in Java 6, you need a Java 6 JRE. Besides, Java 5 is very old and will not be supported anymore after October 30th.